# getting the same directory structure after decompressing a zipped file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I downloaded the zip file from the amazon server(using AWS SDK for unity).The zip file has a folder which has one more folder inside it which contains png files.When I  got the response object from the amazon server,I read it as a byte array and stored as a .zip file. When I double click on zip file I get directory and subdirectory inside it containing png files.Now I need to programatically unzip the file. I am trying to use GZipStream to decompress it,which returns the uncompressed byte array.Now how can I save this byte array so that I retain my folder structure?Also I don't want to use the third party library to decompress the zipped file.

void Start()
    {

```
    UnityInitializer.AttachToGameObject (this.gameObject);
    client = new AmazonS3Client (mAccKey, mSecretKey, mRegion);
    Debug.Log ("Getting the presigned url\n");
    GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest ();
    request.BucketName = mBucketName;
    request.Key = mFileName;
    request.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes (5);
    request.Protocol = Protocol.HTTP;



    GetObjectRequest requestObject = new GetObjectRequest ();
    requestObject.BucketName = mBucketName;
    requestObject.Key = mFileName;
    Debug.Log ("Requesting for the " + mFileName + " contents" + "from the bucket\n" + mBucketName);

    client.GetObjectAsync(mBucketName, mFileName, (responseObj) =>
        {

            var response = responseObj.Response;
            if (response.ResponseStream != null)
            {

                Debug.Log("Recieving response\n");
                using (BinaryReader bReader=new BinaryReader(response.ResponseStream))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = bReader.ReadBytes((int)response.ResponseStream.Length);


                    var zippedPath=Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+zippedFile;
                    File.WriteAllBytes(zippedPath,buffer);

                    var unZippedPath=Application.persistentDataPath+"/"+unZipToFolder;
                    DirectoryInfo directory=Directory.CreateDirectory(unZippedPath);
                    byte[]compressedData=compress(buffer);

                    byte[] unCompressedData=decompress(compressedData);
                    //Debug.Log(unCompressedData.Length);
                    File.WriteAllBytes(unZippedPath+directory,unCompressedData);








                }
                Debug.Log("Response complete");

            }

        });
}


#region GZipStream
public static byte[] compress(byte[] data)
{
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(outStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
        using (MemoryStream srcStream = new MemoryStream(data))
            CopyTo(srcStream, gzipStream);
        return outStream.ToArray();
    }
}


public static byte[] decompress(byte[] compressed)
{
    using (MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(compressed))
    using (GZipStream gzipStream = new GZipStream(inStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    using (MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        CopyTo(gzipStream, outStream);
        return outStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static void CopyTo(Stream input, Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}

#endregion
```

}

folder structure inside the zip file images->sample images->10 png files

Comment: Please add some code, and format your question to be more readable. Read the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first and more people will be willing to help you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GZipStream` can only (de)compress streams. In other words, you cannot restore folder structure using it. Use [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or, if you cannot use framework 4.5, [SharpZipLib](http://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/).

Comment: I want to do it without using third party library.

Comment: As i wrote, use ZipFile which is a part of net framework 4.5. If, because of some reason,  you can not or don't want to use 4.5, you will have to use third party component.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am not using the .net framework 4.5.So using the third party component would be the only solution?

Comment: Thank you Nino. I used SharpZipLib and is working perfectly for me.

Comment: Can anybody tell me how can I  get the progress value of the download using aws sdk for unity?I did not get any property/method giving download progress while downloading the files from amazon server using s3.Please help.